# How to preview ones app inside facebook or add ones app to a "page" as of Jan./'14?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I've created a "Facebook-Page" (translated from German, possibly "fanpage" in Fbs native language) (opposite to "Timeline").

I've also created a Webpage hosted on a Server and added a Facebook App specifying that webpage as a pagetab app. I can manage that app under Facebooks "manage apps" where I can add developers, add test users, disable sandbox mode much much more and the app has an App ID and so on.

**Now, where and how can I preview the pagetab app inside Facebook (Jan./'14) and where and how can I add it to (one of) my "Facebook-Page"(s)?**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/ is outdated as of today and doesn't touch the preview and add-to-page aspect.

Thank you for help!

Comment: What part of page tab tutorial is outdated? (apart from the fact that the new version of the app dashboard is being released so the app settings interface you see may be different)

Comment: By the way, you linked to the 'App on Facebook' tutorial, not hte page tab tutorlai: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: the "Configuring your App" part, particularly the screenshot. 4. and 5. can be right still, I'm sorry for having been too general there possibly.

Comment: I know, I didn't find the other one, thanks for the link! However I already set those settings. My question remains.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the rest of your question is? What part isn't working for you?

Comment: well, there's https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page but for that I have to open the pagetab somehow, not just my hosted Webpage, it has to run in the context of Facebook. I have not seen any means to open (preview) the pagetab app anywhere inside any of my Facebook pages, be it Settings, Management or the Facebook Page, (and neither did I find it in the help), thus the BOLD question.

Comment: I don't think there is any such 'preview' functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**:

Previewing seems unavailable and instead viewing of ones app is done.
Viewing of ones app requires having it added to one of ones Facebook-Pages before.
Adding an app to one of ones Facebook-Pages is accomplished by:

1. Login to Facebook with the account to which the Facebook-Page to which you want to add the app to, belongs, using a webbrowser. Keep this Webbrowser opened.
2. Using this still open webbrowser paste "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=X&next=Y" into its address bar.
3. Replace X by the App-ID of your app (to be found under Facebook Menu Bar -> Settings Icon -> Manage Apps -> My App) you're intending to add here.
4. Replace Y by the pagetab url of this app (to be found under ... -> My App -> Edit App -> Basics -> Pagetab -> Pagetab url (translated from German)).
5. Now press Enter on your keyboard.
6. A webpage resembling a dialogue should load where you can choose a Facebook-Page from a list of the Facebook-Pages belonging to the account you logged into Facebook in 0 inside a drop-down-box to add the app you are intending to add here to.
7. Click "Done" (or possibly named "Confirm") and you're done.

This is of course well hidden, unintuitive and redundant. The app of the App-ID already is configured and then contains a pagetab URL. Having Y be the target Facebook-Page makes much more sense.

How to create a surrounding for test users then who don't have/want to create a test Facebook-Page and have them test the app is beyond the scope of this document. At least test user management appears possible from the management page of ones app.